# How to increment tuple recursively in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I've been asked to create a function that calculates the number of negative, zero and positive numbers on a [Int]. The result should then be written on a tuple (nrOfNeg,nrOfZeros,nrOfPos).

nzp [0,-1,1,2,0,3] = (1,2,3)

**However, the list must be covered only once (meaning that tuple should update every element it is evaluated on [Int]).**

Something like:

```
nzp [***0***,-1,1,2,0,3] = (0,1,0)
nzp [0,***-1***,1,2,0,3] = (1,1,0)
nzp [0,-1,***1***,2,0,3] = (1,1,1)
...
```

This is what I made so far, but it "uses" 3 times the list to calculate.

```
nzp :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int)
nzp l = (neg,zeros,pos)
        where neg = length (filter (<0) l)
              zeros = length (filter (==0) l)
              pos = length (filter (>0) l)
```

Is there any way to increment the tuple specific position while evaluating elements of [Int]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for `foldl`:

```
nzp :: [Int] -> (Int, Int, Int)
nzp = foldl accountForNumber (0, 0, 0)
      where accountForNumber (lt, eq, gt) x | x < 0 = (lt + 1, eq, gt)
            accountForNumber (lt, eq, gt) x | x > 0 = (lt, eq, gt + 1)
            accountForNumber (lt, eq, gt) _ | otherwise = (lt, eq + 1, gt)
```

Comment: Th question is obviously homework so you shouldn't if possible to reveal the solution ;-)

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks. So, am I able to use any function as a parameter of fold?

Comment: Any function with the appropriate type signature:
Since `foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, the function you pass as your first argument must be of type `b -> a -> b`, where `b` is the same as the type of your second argument, in this case `(Int, Int, Int)`

Comment: To avoid relying on compiler optimizations, you should use `foldl'` and ensure that the components of the triples are forced appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

#### The boring way

```
count :: (Num a, Ord a, Foldable f) => f a -> (Int, Int, Int)
count = foldl' go (0, 0, 0) where
  go (!neg, !zer, !pos) x =
    case compare x 0 of
      LT -> (neg + 1, zer, pos)
      EQ -> (neg, zer + 1, pos)
      GT -> (neg, zer, pos + 1)
```

#### The fun way

Use the `foldl` package

```
import qualified Control.Foldl as Fl
import Control.Lens.Fold

countF :: (a -> Bool) -> Fl.Fold a Int
countF p = Fl.handles (filtered p) Fl.length

count = Fl.fold ((,,) <$> countF (<0) <*> countF (==0) <*> countF (>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really *update* a tuple, as value are immutable in Haskell. However, you can create a new one from the previous one with the *updated* value. Hint, use `fold` or simple recursion.

Comment: I thought of generating a list of tuples and then use fold to sum them. But I am covering 2 lists (different, I know, but 2) anyway...

Comment: just fold your list to the tuples. The function in fold take two arguments, the element being *scanned*  and  last tuples.